# Format for Video streaming

Tags: android, video, video-streaming

Which video format would be most suitable for Video Streaming from server to Android Tablets and Android Mobile phones?

`.3gpp or .mpeg4?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its depend on compatibility  there are specific format which are supportable, nicely mention at developer site, have once look.

[Android Supported Media Formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

> For video content that is streamed over HTTP or RTSP, there are additional requirements:
>
> For 3GPP and MPEG-4 containers, the moov atom must precede any mdat atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom.
>
> For 3GPP, MPEG-4, and WebM containers, audio and video samples corresponding to the same time offset may be no more than 500 KB apart. To minimize this audio/video drift, consider interleaving audio and video in smaller chunk sizes.

Comment: That I have checked but my question is which format will be more better for streaming purpose and using which protocol.